# Unable to load offline Google map tiles using Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, mapping

I am a new R user who is trying to create an offline map utilizing RgoogleMaps and Leaflet following this
http://rgooglemaps.r-forge.r-project.org/OfflineMaps-RgoogleMaps-leaflets.html. I've had success up to the point where I try to create the leaflet map. It doesn't seem to want to pull in all the tile files from the local server. If I adjust the URL template to point to a single .png tile then it will pull that single file into the map. But if I use the suggested "http:/localhost:8000/mapTiles/Google/{z}*{x}*{y}.png" nothing is pulled in and it's just a grey background with my one marker.

```
#Get map tiles for offline mapping
ma=GetMapTiles(center=c(lat=42.10188, long=-72.58867), nTiles=c(3,3), zoom=8, type=c("google"), urlBase="http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m", tileDir="~/mapTiles/Google/", CheckExistingFiles=TRUE, TotalSleep=NULL, tileExt=".png", returnTiles=TRUE, verbose=0)
PlotOnMapTiles(ma)

deamon_id <- servr::httd(port=8000, daemon=TRUE)

#plot with leaflet
ma4 = leaflet::leaflet() %>% addTiles ( urlTemplate = "http:/localhost:8000/mapTiles/Google/{z}_{x}_{y}.png")
ma4=ma4 %>% leaflet::setView(42.2626, -71.8023, zoom=8)
ma4=ma4 %>% leaflet::addMarkers(42.2626, -71.8023)
ma4
```